# Async pipe between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++, asynchronous, pipe

I'm trying to send data between C# (server) and C++ (client). Now I can send only one data successfully between them. How can I send more than one value from C# async (in real time) to C++?

C# Server

```
using (NamedPipeServerStream PServer1 =
            new NamedPipeServerStream("MyNamedPipe", PipeDirection.InOut))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server created");
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client connection...");
            PServer1.WaitForConnection();

            Console.WriteLine("Client conencted");

            try
            {
                // Read user input and send that to the client process. 
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(PServer1))
                {
                    sw.AutoFlush = true;
                    Console.Write("Enter text: ");
                    sw.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
                }

            }
            // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken 
            // or disconnected. 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            //PServer1.Close();
        }
```

C++ Client

```
HANDLE hPipe;

//Connect to the server pipe using CreateFile()
hPipe = CreateFile( 
    g_szPipeName,   // pipe name 
    GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
    GENERIC_WRITE, 
    0,              // no sharing 
    NULL,           // default security attributes
    OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
    0,              // default attributes 
    NULL);          // no template file 

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hPipe) 
{
    printf("\nError occurred while connecting" 
        " to the server: %d", GetLastError()); 
    return 1;  //Error
}
else
{
    printf("\nCreateFile() was successful.");
}

//Read server response
char szBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
DWORD cbBytes;
BOOL bResult = ReadFile( 
    hPipe,                // handle to pipe 
    szBuffer,             // buffer to receive data 
    sizeof(szBuffer),     // size of buffer 
    &cbBytes,             // number of bytes read 
    NULL);                // not overlapped I/O 

if ( (!bResult) || (0 == cbBytes)) 
{
    printf("\nError occurred while reading" 
        " from the server: %d", GetLastError()); 
    CloseHandle(hPipe);
    return 1;  //Error
}
else
{
    printf("\nReadFile() was successful.");
}

printf("\nServer sent the following message: %s", szBuffer);

//CloseHandle(hPipe);
```

Comment: Put send/receive code in a loop?

Comment: Tried it, but didn't work as expected

Comment: Then add this info to your question, and specify what 'didn't work' means *exactly*

Comment: 1st thing, you're destroying the pipe server when you're disposing the StreamWriter in your C# code. Same thing goes for your C++ code when you call CloseHandle(hPipe). Secondly, implementing a reusable pipe server can be somewhat tricky, from what I've read it is recommended to create a new client/server stream for every request. After all it's just a stream...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send multiple messages, you will have to setup a loop in both the client and server.

Also, please note that because of the `using` statement, the Pipe's `Dispose()` method is being called and therefore closing it.  So you will have to have the loop inside the `using` block.

So something like:

(ServerSide)

```
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(PServer1))
{
  sw.AutoFlush = true;

  while(Condition) // This could be done by analyzing the user's input and looking for something special...
  {
    Console.Write("Enter text: ");
    sw.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
  }
}
```

Comment: I put a loop in both, seems working fine in server but doesn't work as expected in client. Ex: loop of 3, on server "x", on client "x" "x" "x". Can't pair 1st loop of the server with the client. Any suggestions?